# How to use installed windows 8 apps in other local users?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-store-app

How can I use the apps that previously downloaded and installed in other local accounts?

I don't want to download the apps that installed by other accounts.
I just want to use "Previously Downloaded" app by other accounts. Any idea?

Comment: This is a interesting question, I just recently discovered that no apps that I downloaded as local user where available to another local account or the guest account. I guess this might be for security reasons. I am interested to see if there are ways to change this.

Comment: I'm interested in this question too!